# install previous package version

Tags: upgrade, apt, updates, firefox

I recently updated to firefox 17 during a system upgrade.

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade.
```

How do I revert back to a previous package version? I'd like to get back to firefox 16.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 and I remove firefox 17 to install firefox 16.0.2.
You can try this:

1. Open a terminal and type: `cd /var/cache/apt/archives`
2. Search for the Firefox's 16 deb packages eg:  `ls -l | grep 'firefox' | grep 
   '16.0.02'`
3. In my case I have 4 deb package for firefox 16

[image]
 4. Now, I removed firefox 17 with: `sudo apt-get remove firefox`

[image]
 5. Finally I installed the firefox 16 packages with:

```
sudo dpkg -i `ls -l | grep 'firefox' | grep '16.0.2' | awk '{print $9}' | xargs`
```

[image]

Or once you have the list with the firefox 16 deb packages , you can  install each .deb package with `sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb`

[image]

Hope this will helpful.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks IgnitE.. I didn't know how to escape the reverse quote..