# GTK integration conflicts with qgtk2 platformtheme

Tags: 18.04, telegram, jupyter

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and Telegram updated to 2.7.4 a few days ago.

When I tried to open Jupyter notebook today I got the following error:

```
(telegram-desktop:27524): lib_base-WARNING **: 17:06:20.656: Unfortunately, GTK integration conflicts with qgtk2 platformtheme and style. Therefore, QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME and QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE will be unset.
lib_base-Message: 17:06:20.656: This can be ignored by setting DESKTOP_APP_I_KNOW_ABOUT_GTK_INCOMPATIBILITY environment variable to any value, however, if qgtk2 theme or style is used, this will lead to a crash.
lib_base-Message: 17:06:20.656: GTK integration can be disabled by setting DESKTOP_APP_DISABLE_GTK_INTEGRATION to any value. Keep in mind that this will lead to some features being unavailable.
```

If I remove Telegram in Ubuntu Software, the jupyter notebooks work again. If I reinstall it, it doesn't work anymore

I would like to set back Telegram to an older version or fix this problem if anybody knows how

I have already tried:

```
sudo snap refresh telegram-desktop
```

and installed multiple versions of libcanberra

EDIT: The problem seemed to be my outdated version of Google Chrome. After updating Chrome everything worked again

Comment: Try setting a value to `DESKTOP_APP_DISABLE_GTK_INTEGRATION`. It's better than using an old version of a messenger app that has the potential of exposing your data to an attacker.

Comment: Don't use snap. It clutters your linux, just like windows. You may try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/222243/install-previous-package-version) (not working with snap either)

Comment: I have tried setting the variables now, the last two messages are then gone, but the conflict between GTK and qtgk2 remains. Every time I run 'jupyter notebook' it will open Telegram, which doesn't make any sense

Comment: @Max are you still in trouble? Please check [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1349233/1120310).