# Opening Jupyter-Notebook in terminal opens Telegram Desktop!

Tags: gtk, telegram, jupyter

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

When I want to open Jupyter-Notebook in terminal, the telegram desktop app opens.

The Jupyter-Notebook is actually opened in background. So I can open the browser and use it.

Here is the output:

```
(geospatial) siavash@siavash-fra:~$ jupyter-notebook 
[I 16:59:52.522 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/siavash
[I 16:59:52.522 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 16:59:52.522 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=192817dbf13703bc25bbd1f348df5e9c1c7c9275d579aef3
[I 16:59:52.522 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 16:59:52.526 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/siavash/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-5326-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=192817dbf13703bc25bbd1f348df5e9c1c7c9275d579aef3

(telegram-desktop:5339): lib_base-WARNING **: 16:59:53.204: Unfortunately, GTK integration conflicts with qgtk2 platformtheme and style. Therefore, QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME and QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE will be unset.
lib_base-Message: 16:59:53.204: This can be ignored by setting DESKTOP_APP_I_KNOW_ABOUT_GTK_INCOMPATIBILITY environment variable to any value, however, if qgtk2 theme or style is used, this will lead to a crash.
lib_base-Message: 16:59:53.204: GTK integration can be disabled by setting DESKTOP_APP_DISABLE_GTK_INTEGRATION to any value. Keep in mind that this will lead to some features being unavailable.
Gtk-Message: 16:59:53.412: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 16:59:53.413: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[ALSOFT] (EE) Failed to set real-time priority for thread: Operation not permitted (1)
```

I also looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334938/gtk-integration-conflicts-with-qgtk2-platformtheme) similar question, but it doesn't answer mine.

Comment: Try running it [on a different port](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html#how-do-i-start-the-notebook-using-a-custom-ip-or-port).

Comment: @PedroMaimere Thanks. That worked! So the default port for jupyter-notebook is 8888, when I open it for example on 8889 it doesn't conflict. Does that mean telegram also use 8888? How can I change that for telegram permanently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem: After installing telegram, strangely enough it makes telegram the default application for opening HTML files. That's why after running `jupyter-notebook` in the terminal, it tries to open the link with telegram.

So to solve the problem, simply find any HTML file. Right click on it. Go to `Properties`. In `Open With` tab select your browser and click on `Set as default`.

The problem is solved. Next time telegram won't open. Instead you'll have jupyter-notebook running on your browser.

Answer (score 1):

As noticed, you should run jupyter notebook through a [different port](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html#how-do-i-start-the-notebook-using-a-custom-ip-or-port).

I wasn't able to reproduce this bug, and also couldn't find a way to force telegram-desktop to use a different port, but you can configure jupyter notebook to use a port other than `8888`.

First, check if the file `/home/USERNAME/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` exists. If not, run `jupyter notebook --generate-config`.

Then, open this file and uncomment the following line, changing the port to `8889`, for example:

```
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
                      ^ Change this port to 8889
```

Save the file and run jupyter notebook again. From now on, telegram desktop should not open.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have a strange problem now! This works in `base` environment, but in other envs, the problem still exists, no matter I open the Jupyter on which port.